# why can I not use methods of my extended class correctly?

Tags: java, stack, abstract-class, return-value, abstract

I am working on a project that uses abstract classes. I have mad the class Item, and  then I made a "Snickers" and a "Mars" class that both extend the Item class.

I am using it in stacks, and after I fill these stacks, I am trying to print out the name of the top, in this case, Snickers. I tried calling the getName() method directly, but it tells me that it is undeclared. When I try to use it using the super keyword like `System.out.println(snickersStack.top().super().getName())` there is an error that says "void cannot be derefferenced", which I can't really understand because the method I am trying to use, is a method that returns a String.

This is the Item class:

```
public abstract class Item {
    private float preis;
    private String name;
    private boolean haltbar;
    
    public Item(float pPreis, String pName, boolean pHaltbar)
    {
        preis = pPreis;
        name = pName;
        haltbar = pHaltbar;
    }
    
    public float getPreis() {
        return preis;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public boolean getHaltbar() {
        return haltbar;
    }
    
    public void setPreis(float pPreis) {
        preis = pPreis;
    }
    
    public void setName(String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }
    
    public void setHaltbar(boolean pHaltbar) {
        haltbar = pHaltbar;
    }
}
```

which clearly has the getName() method, this is the Snickers method, which just refferences the Item class:

```
public class Snickers extends Item {
    public Snickers(boolean pHaltbar) { 
        super(1.2f, "Snickers", pHaltbar);
    }
}
```

and this is the way I fill different amounts of Items into the stack, at the bottom there is the line with my problem.

```
public void fuelleStacks() {
    //random int 0 - 7
    randomInt = random.nextInt(8);
    
    //fuelle snickersStack
    while(randomInt != 0) {
        randomBool = random.nextBoolean();
        Snickers snickers = new Snickers(randomBool);
        
        snickersStack.push(snickers);
        randomInt--;
    }
    
    //fuelle marsStack
    randomInt = random.nextInt(8);
    while(randomInt != 0) {
        randomBool = random.nextBoolean();
        Mars mars = new Mars(randomBool);
        
        marsStack.push(mars);
        randomInt--;
    }
    System.out.println(snickersStack.top().super().getName());
}
```

I have declared and initialized the stack itself in the same class, like so:

```
public class Automat {
    public Stack snickersStack;
    
    public Automat() {
        snickersStack = new Stack<Snickers>();
        marsStack = new Stack<Mars>();
    }
}
```

I did not import a Stack class, instead I have another class called Stack that contains this code (that's why I used top(), not peek() like you do with the normal Stack class):

```
public class Stack<ContentType> {

  private class StackNode {

    private ContentType content = null;
    private StackNode nextNode = null;

    public StackNode(ContentType pContent) {
      content = pContent;
      nextNode = null;
    }

    public void setNext(StackNode pNext) {
      nextNode = pNext;
    }

    public StackNode getNext() {
      return nextNode;
    }

    /**
     * @return das Inhaltsobjekt vom Typ ContentType
     */
    public ContentType getContent() {
      return content;
    }
  }

  private StackNode head;
  private int anzahl;

  public Stack() {
    head = null;
    anzahl = 0;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return (head == null);
  }

  public void push(ContentType pContent) {
    if (pContent != null) {
      StackNode node = new StackNode(pContent);
      node.setNext(head);
      head = node;
      anzahl++;
    }
  }

  public void pop() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
      head = head.getNext();
      anzahl--;
    }
  }
  
  public ContentType top() {
    if (!this.isEmpty()) {
      return head.getContent();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
  
  public int getAnzahl() {
      return anzahl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem isn't in anything you pasted; it is in where you declared `snickersStack`. Edit your question and include this part of your code. Preferably, you should paste self-contained code. For this exercise, it seems trivial to do so.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `snickersStack.top().super().getName()`? What do you think this should do?

Comment: Side note: When you get an error in a long expression such as `snickersStack.top().super().getName()` you can debug it by breaking it down into smaller parts and assign each part to a variable. This will show you more precisely where the problem is.

Comment: Another note: indenting the first line of your code is not sufficient. Each line must be indented an additional four spaces. If you don't, then the first four spaces are treated as "here is a line of code" rather than the indentation to actually format your code. Alternatively you can add three backticks above and below each code block for formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snickersStack.top().super().getName()` is an incorrect use of the keyword `super()`. `super()` can only be called as the first line in a constructor. In fact, you use it correctly here:

```
public class Snickers extends Item {
    public Snickers(boolean pHaltbar) { 
        super(1.2f, "Snickers", pHaltbar);
    }
}
```

For more details, [check out this documentation about super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Comment: Yes, that is also what I thought, I think I saw it somewhere on a website, I don't understand why I can't use the getName() method anyways, it should be defined?

Comment: @gone You can if you do it correctly. What `Stack` class are you using? What is the import for `Stack` at the top of your code?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that this is of course not the way you normally use stack classes well, this is not an imported version of the stack class, it is its own class, that's also why it is top(), not peek().

Comment: @gone Please add the `Stack` class to your question. I assume you have `public void top()` right? Is this really what you want? If not, then what should it be instead? Do you have any thoughts about it?

Comment: No, the top method returns a content type, and as you can see in the initialization of the stack, it has a set ContentType, which makes the fact that I can't use the methods that the Snickers ContentType normally should have even weirder

Comment: @gone What do you mean by "I can't use the methods that the Snickers ContentType normally should have"? What happens when you change `snickersStack.top().super().getName()` to `snickersStack.top().getName()`? This is the correct way to do it given your code.

Comment: If I use `snickersStack.top().getName()` it says "undeclared method: getName(...)", but the getName method is declared in the item class, which is the class the Snickers class is extending so I do not understand why it should not be able to use the methods of its parent class

Comment: @gone The way to debug this is to break `snickersStack.top().getName()` into two pieces: `Snickers s = snickersStack.top();` and then `System.out.println(s.getName());`. What happens when you do this?

Comment: @gone After looking more closely at your code, I see this declaration: `public Stack snickersStack;`. Do you see what is missing?

Comment: Yes, I saw what was missing, the correct way is to initialize it like this: `public Stack<Snickers> snickersStack;` and then declare it in the constructor like this: `snickersStack = new Stack<Snickers>();`, thank you very much, this once again is just one of these mistakes where a word of some kind is missing and it messes everything up, tyvm for your help!

Comment: @gone "this once again is just one of these mistakes where a word of some kind is missing and it messes everything up" Welcome to computer programming. In the case of your error, it was because `snickersStack.top()` returned an `Object` because you were using a bare `Stack` rather than the generic `Stack<Snickers>`.

Answer (score 1):

The code `snickersStack.top().super().getName()` has two things wrong.
You need to use `peek()` to look at the top element of the stack.
And `super()` is not a thing either.
If you want to "reach" the `getName()` method you can do so by just using it on the object you get from `peek()`. The method is inherited from the base class.

Comment: This is along the right lines. However, it is difficult to know if `peek()` will solve the problem. We don't know what `Stack` class the OP is using. `top()` isn't in standard `Stack` class. So this should cause a different error.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I did not import a stack class, but I am using another version of the stack that is its own class in the project, that's why it is top, and not peek.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `snickersStack` as raw type:

```
public class Automat {
    public Stack snickersStack;
}
```

That means for the java compiler that it can contain any kind of object. And since `Object` doesn't have a `getName()` method you cannot call `getName()` on the result of `snickersStack.top()`.

To fix this you must declare the snickersStack as a `Stack<Snickers>`:

```
public class Automat {
    public Stack<Snickers> snickersStack;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thomas Kläger, you need to declare the type of your Stack:

```
public class Automat {
/** In your code you forgot the type of the Stack
 * you need to specify the type, for example: Stack<Snickers>, Stack<Item> */
public Stack<Snickers> snickersStack;
public Stack<Mars> marsStack;
public MyStack<Item> itemsStack; // **Using your Stack class, I named it MyStack**

public Automat() {
    /** In Java 8 and newer versions you can omit the type here
     * instead of
     * snickersStack = new Stack<Snickers>();
     * you can write "snickersStack = new Stack<>();" */
    snickersStack = new Stack<>();
    marsStack = new Stack<>();
    itemsStack = new MyStack<>();
}
```

I think you need to understand the use of Polymorphism here and that is why you are confused about using the super() keyword, so I wrote some code so you can see a better use of Polymorphism with abstract classes and OOP:

**Automat.java**

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Stack;
    
public class Automat {
    // In your code you forgot the type of the Stack
    // you need to specify the type, for example: Stack<Snickers>, Stack<Item> 
    public Stack<Snickers> snickersStack;
    public Stack<Mars> marsStack;
    public MyStack<Item> itemsStack; // **Using your Stack class, I named it MyStack**
    
    public Automat() {
        /** In Java 8 and newer versions you can omit the type here
         * instead of
         * snickersStack = new Stack<Snickers>();
         * you can write "snickersStack = new Stack<>();"
         */
         snickersStack = new Stack<>();
         marsStack = new Stack<>();
         itemsStack = new MyStack<>();
     }
     public void fuelleStacks() {
         Random random = new Random();
         //random int 0 - 7
         int randomInt = random.nextInt(8);
         boolean randomBool = false;
    
         //fuelle snickersStack
         while(randomInt != 0) {
             randomBool = random.nextBoolean();
             Snickers snickers = new Snickers(randomBool);
             snickersStack.push(snickers);
             randomInt--;
         }
    
         //fuelle marsStack
         randomInt = random.nextInt(8);
         while(randomInt != 0) {
             randomBool = random.nextBoolean();
             Mars mars = new Mars(randomBool);
             marsStack.push(mars);
             randomInt--;
         }
    
         //fuelle items Stack with Snickers and Mars
         // See the benefit of using Polymorphism here, which I assume is what you
         //      wanted to do in your code.
         // "You want to create an items Stack, with any item Snickers or Mars"
         // This is how I would do it.
         randomInt = random.nextInt(8);
         while(randomInt != 0) {
             randomBool = random.nextBoolean();
             Item itemMars = new Mars(randomBool);
            Item itemSnickers = new Snickers(randomBool);
    
             if (randomInt % 2 != 0) {
                 itemsStack.push(itemMars);
             }
             if (randomInt % 2 == 0) {
                 itemsStack.push(itemSnickers);
             }
             randomInt = random.nextInt(8);
         }
         // let's check the stacks
         if (!snickersStack.isEmpty()) {
             System.out.println("snickersStack: ");
             System.out.println(snickersStack.peek().getName());
             snickersStack.peek().printMyName(); // see the use of super in printMyName()
         } else {
             System.out.println("** Empty Snickers Stack **");
         }
         if (!marsStack.isEmpty()) {
             System.out.println("marsStack: ");
             System.out.println(marsStack.peek().getName());
             marsStack.peek().printMyName(); // see the use of super in printMyName()
         } else {
             System.out.println("** Empty Mars Stack **");
         }
    
         // This is the best part, you have a Stack with items (Snickers, Mars, etc) that you can do operations on it
         // Here you can see the item Stack
         // You do not use super() here, you call super() "within the context of" the Derived class
         //      to refer to a method from the Base class
         // I am using your Stack class here
         if (!itemsStack.isEmpty()) {
             // let's print the items names from the Stack
             System.out.println();
             System.out.println("First item on itemsStack : " + itemsStack.top().getName());
    
             System.out.println("Let's see the items Stack :");
             while (!itemsStack.isEmpty()) {
                 System.out.println("top item: " + itemsStack.top().getName());
                 itemsStack.top().printMyName();// see the use of super in printMyName()
                 itemsStack.pop();
             }
         } else {
             System.out.println("** Empty Items Stack **");
         }
     }
}
```

**Item.java**

```
public abstract class Item {
    private float preis;
    private String name;
    private boolean haltbar;

    public Item(float pPreis, String pName, boolean pHaltbar)
    {
        preis = pPreis;
        name = pName;
        haltbar = pHaltbar;
    }

    public float getPreis() {
        return preis;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean getHaltbar() {
        return haltbar;
    }

    public void setPreis(float pPreis) {
        preis = pPreis;
    }

    public void setName(String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }

    public void setHaltbar(boolean pHaltbar) {
        haltbar = pHaltbar;
    }

    public void printMyName() {
        System.out.println("call printMyName() in Base class Item : " + name);
    }
}
```

**Mars.java**

```
public class Mars extends Item {
    public Mars(boolean pHaltbar) {
        super(2.2f, "Mars", pHaltbar); // you used super() correctly here
    }

    @Override
    public void printMyName() {
        super.printMyName(); // See another way to use super() from Derived class
        System.out.println("call printMyName() in Derived class Mars : " + getName());
    }
}
```

**Snickers.java**

```
public class Snickers extends Item {
    public Snickers(boolean pHaltbar) {
        super(1.2f, "Snickers", pHaltbar); // you used super() correctly here
    }

    @Override
    public void printMyName() {
        super.printMyName(); // See another way to use super() from Derived class
        System.out.println("call printMyName() in Derived class Snickers : " + getName());
    }
}
```

**Demo.java**

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Automat automat = new Automat();
        automat.fuelleStacks();
    }
}
```